# Aurelia: Uncaught Error: doSomething is not a function

Tags: javascript, binding, aurelia

I am having issues with a VERY basic Aurelia app.  On clicking the button, it says it doesn't find doSomething function.  Other buttons in other components work fine. Clearly I am doing something fundamentally wrong here?

app.html:

```
<template>
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
    <require from="./styles.css"></require>
    <require from="./client/person-details.html"></require>

    <person-details></person-details>
</template>
```

person-details.html

```
<template>
    <button click.delegate="doSomething()">clickey</button>
</template>
```

person-details.js

```
export class PersonDetails {
    doSomething() {
        console.log("Doing something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are currently only importing the HTML of `person-details` whereas you should import both the JS and HTML portions (usually done automatically by Aurelia, if you leave out the file extension).

`<require from="./client/person-details.html"></require>`

should be

`<require from="./client/person-details"></require>`